# How to take advantage of browser caching of XAPS

Tags: silverlight, caching, xap

I have a Silverlight Application that currently downloads XAPs on demand using
**Package.DownloadPackageAsync()** from the **System.ComponentModel.Composition.Packaging**  namespace.

As far as I can tell this circumvents any sort of browser caching of XAPS that may take place. Does anyone know how to take advantage of browser caching using on demand downloads ? The only thing i can think of is doing my own caching of XAPs in isolated storage.

Thanks,

Comment: Umm... where do you get this `Packaging` namespace from?

Comment: `Packaging` namespace is from MEF

Comment: @Graeme: Is MEF an additional SDK?  There is no Packaging namespace in the Silverlight 4 Beta documentation on MSDN that I can see?

Comment: Package was removed from the Beta build.  It was refactored and re-added as the DeploymentCatalog in the most recent build. See: http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2010/02/24/mef-silverlight-and-the-deploymentcatalog.aspx

Answer (score 0):

According to Glenn Blocks latest post: "We are looking into cached assembly support in the future."

http://codebetter.com/blogs/glenn.block/archive/2010/03/07/building-hello-mef-part-iv-deploymentcatalog.aspx

That being said, aside from caching the XAP in isolated storage, if you are running OOB you could cache the XAP manually on the local system.

Comment: I'm glad they are thinking about this, meanwhile i guess i'll implement the Isololated storage cache. Good blog post, thanks for the answer.